# How To Find Circle's Inertia Rate with SimpleBlobDetector() : OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, geometry

I'm trying to get "inertia rate" of circle that i have already found. Also i will need to coordinates of circle, but my priority is inertia rate now. My codes on below :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

video = "1.avi"

cam = cv.VideoCapture(video)


while(cam.isOpened()):
flag, frame = cam.read()

grayFrame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

args = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

args.filterByCircularity = True
args.minCircularity = 0.1
args.filterByConvexity = True
args.minConvexity = 0.1
args.filterByInertia = True
args.minInertiaRatio = 0.01
args.filterByArea = True
args.maxArea = 1000000
args.minArea = 300

finder = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(args)
door = finder.detect(grayFrame)

blank = np.zeros((1,1))
drawing = cv.drawKeypoints(frame, door, blank, (0,0,255), cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv.imshow("door", drawing)


if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

the SimpleBlobDetector will give you a list of [KeyPoint](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html)s, one for each contour found.

you should look at:

```
kp.radius # circle radius
kp.pt     # center
kp.confidence # squared inertia ratio
```

[here's the calculation of it](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/features2d/src/blobdetector.cpp#L231-L256)